# Can not install Quantstrat from github

Tags: r, quantstrat

Have followed the processes outlined on the Github repo.

Have tried installed blotter first and then quantstrat. Doesnt work

Have then moved to installing all dependencies first.

```
install.packages("FinancialInstrument",repos="https://github.com/braverock/FinancialInstrument")
```

When trying to install from Github using devtools get the following error.

> > devtools::install_github("braverock/blotter")
> >     Downloading GitHub repo braverock/blotter@master
> >     ✓  checking for file ‘/private/var/folders/_8/zy8__ntx5cx0_lnbybvfjhsr0000gp/T/Rtmp0wtY3O/remotes2547e2faf85/braverock-blotter-67be2c8/DESCRIPTION’ (400ms)
> >     ─  preparing ‘blotter’:
> >     ✓  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
> >     ─  cleaning src
> >     ─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
> >     ─  checking for empty or unneeded directories
> >     ─  looking to see if a ‘data/datalist’ file should be added
> >     ─  building ‘blotter_0.14.8.tar.gz’

- installing *source* package ‘blotter’ ...
  ** using staged installation
  ** libs
  clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c calcPosAvgCost.c -o calcPosAvgCost.o
  calcPosAvgCost.c:31:12: warning: using integer absolute value function 'abs' when argument is of floating point type [-Wabsolute-value]
      if(abs(d_PrevPosQty) > abs(d_PosQty[i])){
         ^
  calcPosAvgCost.c:31:12: note: use function 'fabs' instead
      if(abs(d_PrevPosQty) > abs(d_PosQty[i])){
         ^~~
         fabs
  calcPosAvgCost.c:31:32: warning: using integer absolute value function 'abs' when argument is of floating point type [-Wabsolute-value]
      if(abs(d_PrevPosQty) > abs(d_PosQty[i])){
                             ^
  calcPosAvgCost.c:31:32: note: use function 'fabs' instead
      if(abs(d_PrevPosQty) > abs(d_PosQty[i])){
                             ^~~
                             fabs
  2 warnings generated.
  clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c init.c -o init.o
  clang -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o blotter.so calcPosAvgCost.o init.o -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
  installing to /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/00LOCK-blotter/00new/blotter/libs
  ** R
  ** data
  ** demo
  ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
  Error: (converted from warning) package ‘quantmod’ was built under R version 3.6.2
  Execution halted
  ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘blotter’
- removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/blotter’
  Error: Failed to install 'blotter' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘/var/folders/_8/zy8__ntx5cx0_lnbybvfjhsr0000gp/T//Rtmp0wtY3O/file25475cac4c09/blotter_0.14.8.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue using Sys.setenv(R_REMOTES_NO_ERRORS_FROM_WARNINGS=TRUE)  from https://github.com/r-lib/remotes/issues/434